# Set parent's height depending on the amount of children?

Tags: css

Is it possible to set a parents height in CSS, depending on the amount of children the element has?

Like:

```
.parent:has-1-children {
    height: 60px;
}
.parent:has-2-children {
    height: 110px;
}
.parent:has-3-children {
    height: 160px;
}
```

Or simply:

```
.parent {
    height: calc(this.children() * 50px + 10px);
}
```

?

Comment: Can you show us the HTML? There is a very simple answer to that without much CSS I think. But I need your Elements-HTML-Code

Comment: If the parent have the `height: auto` or nothing declared as `height`, the heigth automatically fits with your requirements, you don't need to make nothing more. However, the only answer to your literal question is **javascript**

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Yes, well, I am simply trying to make an animated dropdown with: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8331169/2378102 where max-height depends and must be calculated, or otherwise the animation-duration will be either to short or to long for different drop-downs, depending on their amount of children inside.

Comment: If you run with `max-height` as in the example, you can put anything in max-height (for example `max-height: 1000px`) and the browser don't go more of the real height of the element. If the element have 100px of height, it never reach the 1000px of max

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Yes, but then the animation will take as much time as needed for 1000px, which means it will be 10 times slower.

Comment: @Murplyx I had a look at it, you can't do it without JavaScript. Would you want a JavaScript solution?

Comment: With jquery, the simple following line: `$('.selector').slideDown(200);` executes what you need with all calculations in javascript. With CSS you can't make calcs.

Comment: @CodeiSir Yes, thing is, I tried inline javascript using style="" inside different dropdowns, but then you can't have a :hover selector

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude NO JQUERY THANK YOU

Comment: @Murplyx did you try putting JavaScript into `style=""` ??? That wont work! ^^

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude javascript right below ;)

Comment: @CodeiSir No, obviously not, but I wish you could do style="hover: blabla"

Comment: @Murplyx well just add a script, that does it. Do you like my answer?

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript solution (with CSS transition)

http://jsfiddle.net/urq1j3aj/

```js
var menu = document.getElementById("menu")
var menuUl = document.getElementById("list")

menu.onmouseover = function() {
  menuUl.style.height = menuUl.scrollHeight + "px"
  menu.classList.add("hover")
}
menu.onmouseout = function() {
  menuUl.style.height = "0"
  menu.classList.remove("hover")
}
```

```css
#menu #list {
  height: 0;
  transition: height 0.15s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #d5d5d5;
}
#menu.hover #list {
  transition: height 0.25s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <a>hover me</a>
  <ul id="list">
    <!-- Create a bunch, or not a bunch, of li's to see the timing. -->
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

## Simplyfied inline JavaScript Version:

```css
#menu #list {
  height: 0;
  transition: height 0.15s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #d5d5d5;
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="this.querySelector('ul').style.height = this.querySelector('ul').scrollHeight + 'px'" 
     onmouseout="this.querySelector('ul').style.height='0'">
  <a>hover me</a>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```